# Probability: busy street intersection problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics, statistics

> At a busy street intersection, it is estimated that a jaywalker will be hit by a car with probability $0.01$. Assuming the individual trips to be independent, find the probability that a jaywalker remains unhit if he crosses the street twice per day for $50$ days.

Comment: Please add your work and tell  us where you have been stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the probability of being hit is $0.01$, this implies the probability of remaining un-hit is $1-0.01=0.99$ as both events are mutually exclusive.
Now, since the jaywalker crosses the road twice a day, the probability of being un-hit for a day is $$(0.99)^2$$
For $50$ days it simply is
$$((0.99)^2)^{50}=(0.99)^{100}\approx 0.366\ldots$$
Hope this clears up your problem.